# Удаление из строки служебных частей речи(союзы, предлоги частицы, междометия и др.) Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, строки, обработка, морфология

Усердно погуглив, на русском и английском, так и не смог найти библиотеку, которая позволяет удалить из строки абсолютно все служебные части речи, если кто знает подскажите ссылку, буду весьма благодарен.

Пример:
Строка до применения: "Однако я так и не смог закончить"
Строка после применения: "я не смог закончить"

Comment: Если удалить из «Однако я так и не смог закончить» предлоги, союзы и частицы, получится «Однако я смог закончить». Ставьте задачу точнее )

Comment: Думаю, вот этот доклад вам будет интересен. https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=4&v=HTzoQBPltY8

Comment: @Nick Volynkin, поправил, просто перечислил не все служебные части речи

Comment: В вашем примере все-таки осталась частица «не». Вы лучше расскажите, какую настоящую задачу вы решаете? Для чего нужно удалять «служебные» части речи?

Comment: @NickVolynkin Реализую неточный поиск в базе, дабы уменьшить погрешность и увеличить точность, вычленяю только главные слова, а в последствии думаю к главным словам применить вычисление корня, дабы построить базу поиска

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если вы хотите удалить избранные части речи из строки, то можно части речи определить [к примеру] используя [`pymorphy2`](http://pymorphy2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/grammemes.html?highlight=POS#russian-pos):

```
import pymorphy2  # $ pip install pymorphy2

def pos(word, morth=pymorphy2.MorphAnalyzer()):
    "Return a likely part of speech for the *word*."""
    return morth.parse(word)[0].tag.POS

words = "Однако я так и не смог закончить".split()
functors_pos = {'INTJ', 'PRCL', 'CONJ', 'PREP'}  # function words
print(*[word for word in words if pos(word) not in functors_pos])
# -> я смог закончить
```

Часть речи по одному только слову может быть неверно определена. В частном случае, вы можете просто свой набор слов для удаления поддерживать.

---

Можно разобрать части речи, используя `averaged_perceptron_tagger_ru` из [`nltk`](http://www.nltk.org/book/ch05.html):

```
import nltk  # $ pip install nltk
# nltk.download('averaged_perceptron_tagger_ru')

words = nltk.word_tokenize("Однако я так и не смог закончить")
functors_pos = {'CONJ', 'ADV-PRO', 'CONJ', 'PART'}  # function words
print(*[word for word, pos in nltk.pos_tag(words, lang='rus')
        if pos not in functors_pos])
# -> я смог закончить
```